# List<Item> to Map<Type, List<Item>>, sort keys, sort values, and process

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a large list of items that I need to convert into a map of items of same type:

```
List<Item> items = //10^6 items of different types
Map<Type, List<Item>> itemsByType = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

for (Item item : items) {
    itemsByType.computeIfAbsent(
        item.getType(), 
        i -> new ArrayList<>()
    ).add(item);
}
```

Each type is then ordered by `long` type identifier; and, each list of type-items is ordered by `long` item identifier. And, finally, the ordered list is processed.

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do all of this...?

Comment: Define *efficient*.

Comment: Less execution time, less garbage generation, less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java-8 [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-)

```
Map<Type, List<Item>> itemsByType = items.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator) //for any sorting you can use sorted with comparator 
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getType));
```

If you want `ConcurrentHashMap` you can use [groupingByConcurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingByConcurrent-java.util.function.Function-)

```
ConcurrentMap<Type, List<Item>> itemsByType = items.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(Item::getType));
```

You can use the overloaded [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) with `TreeMap` so the map is already sorted based on key

```
TreeMap<Type, List<Item>> map = list
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Item::Type,
        () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Type::getId)), 
        Collectors.toList()));
```

You can also collect the map with sorted keys and sorted values in one chain

```
Map<Type, List<Item>> str = list1.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Item::Type, 
            () -> new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparingLong(Type::getId)),
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toList(),
                list -> list.stream()
                    .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Item::getId))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `MultiMap`, e.g., [guava's](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). Here is their code example:

```
   ListMultimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
   for (President pres : US_PRESIDENTS_IN_ORDER) {
     multimap.put(pres.firstName(), pres.lastName());
   }
   for (String firstName : multimap.keySet()) {
     List<String> lastNames = multimap.get(firstName);
     out.println(firstName + ": " + lastNames);
   }
```

... produces output such as:

```
   Zachary: [Taylor]
   John: [Adams, Adams, Tyler, Kennedy]  // Remember, Quincy!
   George: [Washington, Bush, Bush]
   Grover: [Cleveland, Cleveland]        // Two, non-consecutive terms, rep'ing NJ!
   ...
```

A [`TreeMultimap`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) has sorted keys and values, which is what you want, if I understood your title correctly.

A Multimap is particularly useful in case you need to check if a certain value is present for a certain key, because that is supported without getting the collection for the key and then searching that:

```
multimap.containsEntry("John", "Adams");
```